# PDF document language detection

Tags: .net, pdf

Is there any way to get PDF document text language?

Example:
Let's say I have some PDF document in unknown to me language, is there any tool, that gives me opportunity to automatically get PDF document language and store (or ECHO) language name in file?

Regards,
Volodymyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found few useful links, that's better than nothing:
C# example: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10351962/how-to-recogonise-that-data-written-in-pdf-or-doc--is-english-or-not.aspx

Java: http://www.slideshare.net/shuyo/language-detection-library-for-java

Online(Web): http://whatlanguageisthis.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. There is nothing in a PDF file which guarantees to tell you the language, and there is certainly nothing simple to acquire from the file which might help.

If the file uses CIDfonts, then the associated CMap *might* give you a clue by the Ordering key in the CIDSystemInfo, but this is often simply a variant of 'Identity'.

If the fonts (CID or regular) contain ToUnicode CMaps (many do, but it is not a requirement) then you might be able to infer the language from the Unicode values.

Comment: Of course a PDF can have metadata attached that specifies the document language. And a properly tagged PDF will have this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the text from the PDF, you can use the [Google Translate API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) to detect the language. This is a paid web service, though.

Comment: If I am going for `ocr` of a text using a tool such as `tesseract`, I'd need the language first, is there something I can do about it?